# How to get sass to compile a dev and production version of css?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm looking at a way to compile my sass into 2 different outputs for development and production. I've been able to achieve this by adopting the following method which works fine https://coderwall.com/p/gqqfgw/sass-compass-compile-two-different-files-for-development-and-production-environment-take-2

The issue i'm having is that I need the content of the output to be different. For the CMS i'm using any files (images, fonts etc) referenced in the css need to be converted into tags (unique to the CMS) whereas for my dev version I need the local path to the image.

I've been able to toggle between them by using a variable in a sass file like so:

```
@if $output == dev {
        background: #FFFFFF url('../images/this-is-my-local-image.jpg') 0 0 repeat-x;
    } @else {
        background: #FFFFFF url('<IMG type="media" id="216155" formatter="path/*"/>') 0 0 repeat-x;
    }
```

However I need a way to be able to output the file in both variations without having to go in and change the $output variable every time.

I've done some reading up on using variables in the config.rb file but can't find out how I should be going about achieving what I need.

Any advice or a point in the right direct would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you make 2 dedicated output files that will be compiled.

dev.scss

```
$output = 'dev'
@include your files
```

prod.scss

```
$output = 'prod'
@include your files
```

So you just have to switch out the generated files.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. If I wanted my production version to be compressed but my dev version not would that have to done through the config.rb file?

Comment: well i don't know what you using but have a look at minify and uglify

Comment: To compile I compass watch the folder with the config.rb file and I set the output_style setting to compressed for my minified version

Comment: well i just have experience with gulp so i cant realy help you here :(

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create a separate sass file for dev and production. In the new file you can set the value for `$output` as `dev` and `prod` respectively and then import the sass file that has all the css defined in the next line. The output css generated will use the variable value defined in the respective file.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. If I wanted my production version to be compressed but my dev version not would that have to done through the config.rb file?